# How i can add "Installation language" options when installing SharePoint add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin

We have a SharePoint provider hosted app, installed inside our app catalog, as follow:-
[image]

the app will add some remote event receivers to out lists. the app was working well, but today we have removed the app >> test how the site will work without the app >> but when we try to re-install the app we got 1 installation error without any description, as follow:-
[image]

so i got confused, as the same app got installed correctly 3 days ago >> i contact Microsoft and they mentioned that i need to specify the installation language for the app, currently the list is empty as follow:-
[image]

now to follow what Microsoft has suggested, **can anyone advice how i can add a language for the app?**? i followed the steps mentioned in this link to create the app @ https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-remote-event-receiver-sharepoint-online/.. again the same app (without installation language worked well for us 3 days ago).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it doesn’t work on second installation but here are some references on SharePoint Add-in localization. It should give you the options to choose installation language for the app.

In addition, the display language for the app usually goes with the site settings, instead of the installation language option while being added to the site.

References:

[Localization in the SharePoint Add-in model.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/localization-sharepoint-add-in)

[Localize SharePoint Add-ins.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/localize-sharepoint-add-ins)